# Change div opacity on scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll, opacity

How can I make it so that when you scroll down the page, the next DIV fades on top of the previous?

I've set up this fiddle to illustrate it better: http://jsfiddle.net/meEf4/176/
So for example if you're halfway down the page, the background is blue.

Edit: Here's the contents of that jsFiddle, in case that ever explodes and somebody is stuck with a similar issue.

```
<style>
html, body, #red, #green, #blue { height: 100%}
#container { height: 300%}
#red, #green, #blue { 
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0; 
    width: 100%;
}
#red { background:red; z-index: 5}
#blue { background:blue; z-index: 4}
#green { background:green; z-index: 3}​    
</style>

<div id="container">
    <div id="red"></div>
    <div id="blue"></div>
    <div id="green"></div>
</div>​
```

Comment: I think you need to play around with the math.. replace the target..css('opacity', scrollPercent) with $("#red").css('opacity', scrollPercent/3); $("#blue").css('opacity', scrollPercent/2);$("#green").css('opacity', scrollPercent); See if that helps.

Comment: Please always include the relevant code within your question.  External links are great but if they cease to exist, your question should still be useful to others.

Comment: It's really just for illustration, because I can't find the words to describe it properly. But I see your point; post updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it something like this:

```
var target = $('div.background');
var targetHeight = target.height();
var containerHeight = $('#container').outerHeight();

var maxScroll = containerHeight - targetHeight;
var scrollRange = maxScroll/(target.length-1);

$(document).scroll(function(e){
    var scrollY = $(window).scrollTop();
    var scrollPercent = (scrollRange - scrollY%scrollRange)/scrollRange;
    var divIndex = Math.floor(scrollY/scrollRange);

    target.has(':lt(' + divIndex + ')').css('opacity', 0);
    target.eq(divIndex).css('opacity', scrollPercent);
    target.has(':gt(' + divIndex + ')').css('opacity', 1);
});​
```

**[WORKING DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/meEf4/222/)**

You map the scroll value to the background div you need to target using the `maxScroll value` divided by `the number of background divs - 1`. This number is the scroll range that one background div has to cover. Then you calculate the scroll percentage for that div by using the `scroll value` modulus `the scroll range`, that way you get a value between 1 and 0 for the target div.

Then you set your target div to the calculated value, the divs below have opacity 1, the divs above it have opacity 0 (because they went through their range of 1 to 0 before)

Comment: One small issue is that it jumps to blue at the very bottom for some reason.

Comment: @James Montagne That was an issue with calculating the divIndex value. It's fixed by using floor now.

Comment: @A.M.K indeed, only 5 or so are mine :)

Comment: Wicked! Great solution, thank you. BTW, I only picked that fiddle up at edit number 170-something ;)

Comment: You're welcome! Ahhh that explains a lot :) I noticed the 180 and thought lots of people were working on this!

Comment: One more thing, any idea why this might not work in IE? I know opacity isn't supported, but for some reason setting filters doesn't work. The filters do work directly from the CSS, but they aren't being set inline! http://jsfiddle.net/meEf4/216/

Comment: I've got only mac computers here, somebody else will have to look at this... Sorry!

Comment: BTW, it was "window.scrollY" causing problems in IE. "$(window).scrollTop()" works. Thanks again Jeroen!

Answer (score 1):

This solution can be improved to make it more generic, but it's a start

```
$(document).ready(function() {

      var colordivs = $('#container div');

      $(document).scroll(function(e) {
          var scrollPercent = ($(window).scrollTop() / $('#container').outerHeight()) * 100;

          if (scrollPercent > 0) {
              if (scrollPercent < 33) {
                  var opacity = 1 - (scrollPercent / 33);
                  $(colordivs[0]).css('opacity', opacity);
              }
              else if (scrollPercent > 66) {
                  var opacity = 1 - (scrollPercent / 100);
                  $(colordivs[0]).css('opacity', 0);
                  $(colordivs[1]).css('opacity', 0);
                  $(colordivs[2]).css('opacity', opacity);
              }
              else if (scrollPercent > 33) {
                  var opacity = 1 - (scrollPercent / 66);
                  $(colordivs[0]).css('opacity', 0);
                  $(colordivs[1]).css('opacity', opacity);
              }
          }
      });

  });
```