# Simple CSS change when another div hits top of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have looked at different posts and have found similar solutions, but none of them allowed me to do what I need.  I have am trying to copy the effect found on this URL http://www.envisionboston.com/

When the image gets to the top of the page the logo switches and the div changes sizes... In the past I found a way to set when a certain div gets to the top of the page that you can change or add to the css element.

Before its to the top `<div class="topbar">` when the image gets to the top you change it to something like `<div class="topbar fixed">`

Another issue I have is they have Headway themes which does nto allow me to edit everything so the div is in a ID and not a CLASS, I am not sure if this changes things but it might.

I know it should be something I should be able to figure out but I have been on this for hours!

Comment: Set a listener to window.onscroll and check the window.scrollY property. I.e. in your event listener, _if(window.scrollY > scrollPoint) { changeDivSizeNStuff(); }_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I took some time and found this great answer on stackoverflow to change the opacity while scrolling, and combined it with a class removal/addition conditional:

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tXbL2/)

Super helpful stackoverflow thread with link to jsfiddle for change opacity on scroll:

[Change div opacity on scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425702/change-div-opacity-on-scroll)

As far as the effect that makes the image look "smaller," it's actually an illusion. The image's div overflow is hidden, so on the scroll event, javascript adjusts the top margin, "pushing" it down. This essentially pushes the image under the < div > below it. When I have a bit more time, I'll see if I can also work this into the answer. Cheers

Page with desired effect:
http://www.envisionboston.com/

Block of code courtesy of Stack link mentioned above:

```
function fader() {
    var b = $('.blue'),
        wh = $(window).height(),
        dt = $(document).scrollTop(),
        elView, opacity;
        h = $("#headerArea").height();
    b.each(function () {
        elView = wh - ($(this).offset().top - dt);

        if (window.pageYOffset > (h + 50)) {
            $("#headerArea").removeClass("withHeader").addClass("withoutHeader");
        } else {
            $("#headerArea").removeClass("withoutHeader").addClass("withHeader");
        }
        if (elView > 0) { // Top of DIV above bottom of window.
            opacity = 1 - 1 / (wh + $(this).height()) * elView;
            if (opacity > 0) // Bottom of DIV below top of window.
            $(this).css('opacity', opacity);
        }
    });
}
// Event on scroll
$(document).bind('scroll', fader);
```

---

Original answer:

Per the link you listed "site.js" file, here is the code that is making that happen:

Looking at the HTML file you'll find the class that is being referenced ".main-image-wrapper" 

The code checks to see if the desired class exists

```
if (Y.one('.main-image-wrapper'))
```

And then says if the current vertical position of the page is greater than the main image height + 80 pixels, then add a class that hides the header

```
if ( (window.pageYOffset > (this.mainImageHeight + 80)) ) {
                Y.one('body').addClass('header-hidden');
```

The class is removed by the else of the above documented conditional. You'll also notice that the header height is changed in this else conditional as well.

```
  else {
            Y.one('body').removeClass('header-hidden');
            this.headerHeight = header.get('offsetHeight');
 }
```

There's a great deal of styling and other subtleties happening, but basically: check where your y position is on the page and if this is greater than your image height + number of desired pixels (80 in this case) then add a class to hide the header; Otherwise, show it.

Complete block of code below for your reference.

```
if (Y.one('html.no-window-orientation')) {
      var scrollStates = function () {
        if (Y.one('.main-image-wrapper')) {
          // 80 is main content padding
          if ( (window.pageYOffset > (this.mainImageHeight + 80)) ) {
            Y.one('body').addClass('header-hidden');
            this.headerHeight = header.get('offsetHeight');
            if (Y.one('.contact-inner-wrapper')) {
              Y.all('.contact-inner-wrapper').setStyle('marginTop', (this.headerHeight + 5));
            }
          } else {
            Y.one('body').removeClass('header-hidden');
            this.headerHeight = header.get('offsetHeight');
            if (Y.one('.contact-inner-wrapper')) {
              Y.all('.contact-inner-wrapper').setStyle('marginTop', (this.headerHeight + 5));
            }
          }
          Y.one('.main-image-wrapper').setStyle('opacity', (1 - (window.pageYOffset / parseInt(Y.Squarespace.Template.getTweakValue('bannerImageHeight'), 10))));
          Y.one('.main-image-wrapper').setStyle('top', -(window.pageYOffset / 3));
        } else {
          if ( (window.pageYOffset >= 80) ) {
            Y.one('body').addClass('header-hidden');
            this.headerHeight = header.get('offsetHeight');
            if (Y.one('.contact-inner-wrapper')) {
              Y.all('.contact-inner-wrapper').setStyle('marginTop', (this.headerHeight + 5));
            }
          } else {
            Y.one('body').removeClass('header-hidden');
            this.headerHeight = header.get('offsetHeight');
            if (Y.one('.contact-inner-wrapper')) {
              Y.all('.contact-inner-wrapper').setStyle('marginTop', (this.headerHeight + 5));
            }
          } 
        }
      };

  scrollStates();
  Y.one(window).on('scroll', function() {
    scrollStates();
  });
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation on how this works so the OP understands it

Comment: Sure! Stackrookie, feel free to suggest any other edits / improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your feedback it was used and really helped, what I did was as follows, if you have any tips in cause I did somethign that is not the best way let me know as I am still learning jQuery

Thanks

```
<script>


jQuery(function ($) {

  $(window).load(function() {

    if ( $('.home').length) { 

    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var height = $(window).scrollTop();
          if(height  > 500 ) {
            $('#wrapper-7').addClass( "wrapper-7-changed" ); 
            $('.wrapper-mirroring-7').addClass( "wrapper-mirroring-7-changed" ); 
            $('.social-icon').addClass( "social-icon-changed" ); 
            $('#block-7 li.widget').addClass( "widget-changed" );

            $('#block-1').addClass( "block-1-changed" );

            $('#block-9').addClass( "block-9-changed" );

            $('#wrapper-6').addClass( "wrapper-6-changed" );
            $('.wrapper-mirroring-6').addClass( "wrapper-mirroring-6-changed" );

          } else {
            $('#wrapper-7').removeClass( "wrapper-7-changed" );
            $('.wrapper-mirroring-7').removeClass( "wrapper-mirroring-7-changed" ); 
            $('.social-icon').removeClass( "social-icon-changed" );
            $('#block-7 li.widget').removeClass( "widget-changed" );
            $('#block-1').removeClass( "block-1-changed" );
            $('#block-9').removeClass( "block-9-changed" );
            $('#wrapper-6').removeClass( "wrapper-6-changed" );
            $('.wrapper-mirroring-6').removeClass( "wrapper-mirroring-6-changed" );
          }   

       });

    } else {

    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var height = $(window).scrollTop();
          if(height  > 50 ) {
            $('#wrapper-7').addClass( "wrapper-7-changed" ); 
            $('.wrapper-mirroring-7').addClass( "wrapper-mirroring-7-changed" ); 
            $('.social-icon').addClass( "social-icon-changed" ); 
            $('#block-7 li.widget').addClass( "widget-changed" );

            $('#block-1').addClass( "block-1-changed" );

            $('#block-9').addClass( "block-9-changed" );

            $('#wrapper-6').addClass( "wrapper-6-changed" );
            $('.wrapper-mirroring-6').addClass( "wrapper-mirroring-6-changed" );

          } else {
            $('#wrapper-7').removeClass( "wrapper-7-changed" );
            $('.wrapper-mirroring-7').removeClass( "wrapper-mirroring-7-changed" ); 
            $('.social-icon').removeClass( "social-icon-changed" );
            $('#block-7 li.widget').removeClass( "widget-changed" );
            $('#block-1').removeClass( "block-1-changed" );
            $('#block-9').removeClass( "block-9-changed" );
            $('#wrapper-6').removeClass( "wrapper-6-changed" );
            $('.wrapper-mirroring-6').removeClass( "wrapper-mirroring-6-changed" );
          }   

       });



    }

  });

}); 
</script>
```

Than the CSS that is mixed in so probably too much to post but just used a transition effect with CSS3 so when it adds the class it 'moves'